# Angular 9 access component in directive

Tags: angular, ivy, angular9

I upgraded an angular 8 app to an agular 9 app.
In one of my directives I access the component trough the viewcontainer _data attribute. This no longer seems to exist in angular 9. How can I access the component in angular 9 ?

I have multiple inputs with an viewchild 'errorContainer'. They all inherit from Abstractinput. This way when I have a formcontroll, trough the directive I can put errors on the components.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[formControl], [formControlName]'
})
export class DefaultControlErrorDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

    constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
      const component = this.vcr['_data'].componentView.component
    }
}
```

Abstract input:

```
@Component({
    template: ``
})
export class InputAbstractComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    @ViewChild('errorContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) errorContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
}
```

Implementation of abstract input

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tg-form-input',
    templateUrl: 'input.html',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class InputComponent extends InputAbstractComponent implements AfterViewInit {
}
```

Input.html

```
<div #errorContainer></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just inject your component

```
constructor(myComponent: MyComponent) {
}
```

if the component isn't always the same component you could do this through providing it with some token

```
@Component({
providers: [{provide: COMPONENT_FOR_DIRECTIVE_TOKEN, useExisting: AnyComponent}]
})
class AnyComponent {
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the token ? I have a viewchild in my component I would like to access.     @ViewChild('errorContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) errorContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

Comment: where do you want to use a directive ?

Comment: I have multiple components, that all have a viewchild: <div #errorContainer></div> (TextInputComponent, RadioInputComponent ...)I defined the viewchild in an abstract component where these inherit from. But if I inject the AbstractComponent int my directive, the viewchild does not exist.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? in version 9 you can add an empty `@Component()` decorator to the superclass. in lower versions you would be required to copy that viewchild declaration to all of the inheritants as old engine doesn't support metadata inheritance

Comment: I have added more information in the question. I am using angular 9. In angular 8 this was working, but in angular 9 it no longer works.

Comment: In theory this makes sense, but in practice it yells (inside the directive c-tor), that no provider is set for the injection token. But I'm defining it exactly as you're doing (except that I'm using forwardRef(() => AnyComponent).